# DNN 9: how to change TextEditor standard behaviour?

Tags: dotnetnuke, behavior, dotnetnuke-9, dnn9

I'm new in DNN world,
I would like to change the texteditor behaviour in order to replace self-defined placeholders (retrieved from DB) with specific text.
I would like to modify the standard behaviour in order to apply this feature across the entire portal wherever a texteditor is used.

Is there a way to accomplish the task? Is there a best practice to achieve this kind of feature?

Thanks in advance,

Giorgio

Answer (score 0):

The text editor in DNN is driven by the so called HTML Editor provider, in case of DNN 9 this provides the functionality of CK Editor.

To customize the editor, go to Settings :: Site Settings :: Site Behaviour :: More, and click on "Open HTML Editor Manager".

The following links can be helpful:

[Help! DNN CKEditor is cleaning my HTML](https://dnncommunity.org/blogs/Post/2841/Help-DNN-CKEditor-is-cleaning-my-HTML)

[Customizing DNN’s Default HTML Editor Provider - CKEditorProvider](https://dnncommunity.org/blogs/Post/8202/Customizing-DNN-s-Default-HTML-Editor-Provider-CKEditorProvider)

[Adding Custom Styles to CKEditorProvider](https://dnncommunity.org/blogs/Post/8371/Adding-Custom-Styles-to-CKEditorProvider)